# Is it forbidden to have more than one Roth account?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, roth-401k

Is there any conflict or any rule against having a Roth IRA and a 401k with Roth contributions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. No rule against it. There are rules concerning how much you can contribute to each in a year (which are easily searchable and change yearly), but no rule against having both.

Comment: @Rich whenever you change jobs, you'll of course get a new 401(k) account.  If you're employed under slightly different names ("Richard Smith" vs. "Richard J Smith III" vs. "Richard J Smith"), it can be hard to roll over old 401(k) accounts into an existing IRA at another company.  Thus, you either keep it in the 401(k) or roll it over into an IRA with that same administrator.  Thus you have multiple (Roth or traditional IRAs).

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn. That's very helpful.